# A big table performance vs a small table with some joins

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to know if I have a big table (50 columns and 50 millions records) and I want to use select query, and if I split my big table to a smaller table (20 columns and 50 millions records) with some joins in some small tables (about 5 columns) and I want to use the same select, which of these manners is better in terms of speed?

For example:

First case with a huge table:

```
select username,password,nationalAdd from baseTBL
```

Second case with a smaller table and some joins:

```
select username,password,nationalAdd from baseTBL
inner join dependTBL1 on baseTBL.user_id=dependTBL1.id 
inner join dependTBL2 on baseTBL.national_id=dependTBL2.id
```

Comment: Have you considered partitions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html

Comment: There is no  general answer.  Try it and see for your case.  But far more important is update anomalies.  Suppose a user changes his password.  With your big table,  you have to search for **every** occurrence of the old paswwrd and correct all of them.  What a mess!     Unless you are building a data warehouse, you want to avoid these update anomalies.  Consider learning data normalization.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the answer is: no performance benefit to Vertical partitioning.  Also, it is rare to get a performance benefit from Horizontal partitioning.

I'll address Vertical here.

- Don't splay an array across columns.  Examples: home/work/cell phone numbers; multiple addresses.  Better to have a 1:many relationship to another table.
- If you have some columns that are "rarely" present, consider vertical partitioning for them, but leave out the rows instead of having `NULLs`.
- If you will be having a `WHERE` clause touching both tables after ther partitioning, this is really bad for performance.  Keep all the search criteria in the main partition.
- If some column has a lot of repeated values, and the values are 'lengthy', consider 'normalizing' those values.  (This works a lot like vertical partitioning, but it is considered a different thingie.)
- Don't over-normalize.  Example:  break out city+state+postal_code+country into a single `Location` table, not 4 tables.

Bottom line:  Your question is too vague to give you the answer that applies to *your* schema.